# Fragment is not loading from the SideMenu

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to load a fragment from the SideMenu. There is a listview in the side menu from where I want to load a Fragment in the application. There are 3 items in the list view. A code for clicking on 0th and 3rd position is working fine, but not working for 1st position ie i==1.

what i have to do for this !

```
package comm.design.amer.sidemenu_new;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;<code>

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<listView> Listview = new ArrayList<listView>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.slideview);
        //Create the ListView Items
        Listview.add(new listView("page1", "enter", R.drawable.a));
        Listview.add(new listView("page2", "enter", R.drawable.b));
        Listview.add(new listView("page3", "enter", R.drawable.c));
        Listview.add(new listView("page4", "enter", R.drawable.d));
        //Call the Adapter
        mycomstumerAdapter adapter = new mycomstumerAdapter(this, Listview);
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
//make selection
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                selectItem(i);
            }
        });
     }

     public void selectItem (int i){

         if (i==0){
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"bn",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
         else if (i==1) {
             Fragment1 fragment0 = new Fragment1();
             FragmentManager fragmentm = getFragmentManager();
             fragmentm.beginTransaction()
                 .add(R.id.linear,fragment0)
                 .commit();
         }
         else if (i==2)
             finish();
     }

     public class mycomstumerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

         Context context;
         ArrayList<listView> Listview;

         public mycomstumerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<listView> Listview) {
             this.context = context;
             this.Listview = Listview;
         }

         @Override
         public int getCount() {
             return Listview.size();
         }

         @Override
         public Object getItem(int i) {
             return Listview.get(i);
         }

         @Override
         public long getItemId(int i) {
             return 0;
         }

         @Override
         public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
             View view1;
             if (view == null) {
                 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                 view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
             } else
                 view1 = view;

             TextView title = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.textView);
             TextView detail = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
             ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view1.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

             title.setText(Listview.get(i).Title);
             detail.setText(Listview.get(i).Detail);
             imageView.setImageResource(Listview.get(i).imageView);

             return view1;
         }
     }

 }
```

Comment: can you share more details

Comment: work correctly means?? Be specific about your problem.

Comment: THANKS for the quick reply , in my ListView when i click the first Item the message appear , and also for the third Item the App Exit , but for the second Item (i=1) which include the fragment , doesn't work .

Answer (score 2):

In your code I have seen you are using add fragment instead of that try with replacing the fragment. See the below code:-

```
Fragment1 fragment0 = new Fragment1();
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.linear,fragment0);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: I used the both , but didn't work , THANKS for your answer

Comment: You are missing fragmenttransaction objet. Do as follows:-

Comment: with getSupportFragmentManager yes , but with the getFragementManager it work correctly , except what i said "I click in the second Item but it not reponse to my clicks !"